# "Change the way users log on or off" using AutoIT Win XP

Tags: autoit

I'm wondering if there is a way, and how to go about it, to change User Account Control settings in Win 7? AutoIt doesn't seem to recognise the clickable options in User Accounts as being Buttons, and I can't know for sure what the mouse pointer coordinates are so I don't want to click blindly and hope to hit it.

If there is a solution, does it differ for Win XP?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Maybe there is another way to directly change something by command.

Comment: Specifically, I have an XP machine (not the one I'm writing the script on unfortunately) that I need to get into "Change the way users log on and off" -> disable "Use Welcome Screen" and "Use Fast User Switching". It's not the biggest issue in the world, but every few seconds I can save in the setup process may help